# WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 Sharepoint 2013 SSO Passive STS failing

Tags: sharepoint, wso2, sharepoint-2013, saml, opensaml

I followed the [SSO for Microsoft Sharepoint Web Applications with WSO2 Identity Server tutorial](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2015/05/tutorial-sso-for-microsoft-sharepoint-web-applications-with-wso2-identity-server/), but I am receiving a SOAP error in the wresult on the form that POSTs back to SharePoint.

The soapenv:Reason contains the following text:

> Error in creating a SAMLToken using Opensaml library

I've enabled DEBUG logging globally in WSO2 Identity Server, and I can see the error response, but I can't figure out why it is happening:

```
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:18,921] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sts.passive.PassiveSTSService} -  Retrieving wreply url for : Portal in tenant : carbon.super {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sts.passive.PassiveSTSService}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:18,921] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sts.passive.PassiveSTSService} -  Setting ReplyTo URL : hxxp://portal.domain/_trust for Realm : Portal {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sts.passive.PassiveSTSService}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:18,937] DEBUG {org.apache.rahas.client.STSClient} -  Creating request with request type: hxxp://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issue and applies to: Portal {org.apache.rahas.client.STSClient}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:18,937] DEBUG {org.apache.rahas.client.STSClient} -  Using RSTTemplate: <sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate xmlns:sp="hxxp://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"><wst:TokenType xmlns:wst="hxxp://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">hxxp://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1</wst:TokenType><wst:KeyType xmlns:wst="hxxp://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">hxxp://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/SymmetricKey</wst:KeyType><wst:KeySize xmlns:wst="hxxp://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">256</wst:KeySize><wst:Claims xmlns:wst="hxxp://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512" xmlns:wsp="hxxp://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512" wsp:Dialect="hxxp://wso2.org/claims"><wsid:ClaimType xmlns:wsid="hxxp://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity" Uri="{WindowsAccountName|123456789}"></wsid:ClaimType></wst:Claims></sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate> {org.apache.rahas.client.STSClient}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:18,937] DEBUG {org.apache.rahas.client.STSClient} -  Extracting key size from the RSTTemplate:  {org.apache.rahas.client.STSClient}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:18,937] DEBUG {org.apache.rahas.client.STSClient} -  Key size from RSTTemplate: 256 {org.apache.rahas.client.STSClient}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:18,952] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sts.passive.processors.RequestProcessor} -  STSTimeToLive read from carbon.xml in passive STS 1800000 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sts.passive.processors.RequestProcessor}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:18,999] DEBUG {org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory} -  Using Crypto Engine [org.wso2.carbon.security.util.ServerCrypto] {org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:19,046] DEBUG {org.apache.xml.security.Init} -  Registering default algorithms {org.apache.xml.security.Init}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:19,140] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.provider.AttributeCallbackHandler} -  Loading claims {org.wso2.carbon.identity.provider.AttributeCallbackHandler}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:19,140] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.IdentityClaimManager} -  IdentityClaimManager singleton instance created successfully {org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.IdentityClaimManager}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:19,140] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.ClaimInvalidationCache} -  My Hash code of Claim cache is : 1 {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.ClaimInvalidationCache}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:19,156] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.ClaimInvalidationCache} -  Shared Hash code of Claim cache is : 1 {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.ClaimInvalidationCache}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:19,156] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.provider.AttributeCallbackHandler} -  Processing claim data {org.wso2.carbon.identity.provider.AttributeCallbackHandler}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:19,156] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.provider.AttributeCallbackHandler} -  Populating claim values {org.wso2.carbon.identity.provider.AttributeCallbackHandler}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:19,187] DEBUG {org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder} -  WARNING: The current state of the parser is not equal to the state just received from the parser. The current state in the paser is END_ELEMENT the state just received is END_DOCUMENT {org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:19,187] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.handlers.addressing.AddressingOutHandler} -  includeOptionalHeaders=false {org.apache.axis2.handlers.addressing.AddressingOutHandler}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:19,187] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.handlers.addressing.AddressingOutHandler} -  WSAHeaderWriter: isFinal=true addMU=false replace=false includeOptional=false role=null {org.apache.axis2.handlers.addressing.AddressingOutHandler}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:19,187] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.client.Options} -  getAction (urn:getResponseResponse) from org.apache.axis2.client.Options@4cdb77b9 {org.apache.axis2.client.Options}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-29 15:39:19,187] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalResponder} -  Response - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="hxxp://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="hxxp://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:Action>urn:getResponseResponse</wsa:Action><wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:83ee0d80-39ff-428f-92b9-bad675cdb820</wsa:RelatesTo></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><ns:getResponseResponse xmlns:ns="hxxp://org.apache.axis2/xsd"><ns:return xmlns:xsi="hxxp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ax2364="hxxp://passive.sts.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xsi:type="ax2364:ResponseToken"><ax2364:authenticated>true</ax2364:authenticated><ax2364:context>hxxp://portal.domain/_layouts/15/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2F</ax2364:context><ax2364:replyTo>hxxp://portal.domain/_trust</ax2364:replyTo><ax2364:responsePointer xsi:nil="true"></ax2364:responsePointer><ax2364:results>&lt;soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="hxxp://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"&gt;&lt;soapenv:Code&gt;&lt;soapenv:Value&gt;Sender&lt;/soapenv:Value&gt;&lt;soapenv:Subcode&gt;&lt;soapenv:Value xmlns:sts="hxxp://wso2.org/passivests"&gt;sts:InvalidRequest&lt;/soapenv:Value&gt;&lt;/soapenv:Subcode&gt;&lt;/soapenv:Code&gt;&lt;soapenv:Reason&gt;&lt;soapenv:Text&gt;Error in creating a SAMLToken using Opensaml library&lt;/soapenv:Text&gt;&lt;/soapenv:Reason&gt;&lt;soapenv:Detail&gt;none&lt;/soapenv:Detail&gt;&lt;/soapenv:Fault&gt;</ax2364:results></ns:return></ns:getResponseResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalResponder}
```

http URIs changed to hxxp so that I can submit this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The catalina config was set to use the wrong alias in the keystore for encrypting private communications. In my case, the specified alias didn't exist at all. Changed it to a valid alias and now it is working as expected.